# How to Calculate Collector Surface and Savings?

Tags: statistics, random-variables, physics

I am interested in making a calculation formula for a solar system for water heating. I have done my research but I am looking for a simple formula which uses only the 3 Arguments (Number of people in the house, Personal needs for hot water and the direction of the house). For the Solar Collector Efficiency the value is 0.72 and the Country for which my calculation is made is Albania with a Solar Rate of 1550kWh. If anyone can help me please send it to me in an understandable form since I need to convert it in a PHP Formula.

Comment: Post that in Physics.SE may be this is a question that is better for the physics plataform